# Call java class from bat file

Tags: java, batch-file, classpath

I want to run a java class from a .bat file.
I currently have the following in the .bat file:

```
@echo off
set path=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin
javac src\pt\logica\mne\job\TriggerLembrete.java
echo Successfully Compiled
pause

java src\pt\logica\mne\job\TriggerLembrete
pause
```

When I run this occurs many errors it says that some package no.

The .bat file is in ...\AgendamentosOnline and the class I want to run in ..\AgendamentosOnline\src\pt\logica\mne\job

This class uses some jar that are in ...\AgendamentosOnline\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib

I think the error has to do with the fact that he did not know where the jar. How do I define this in the .bat file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming the Java source is correct then you should execute it as `java -cp src pt.logica.mne.job.TriggerLembrete`

Comment: Can you tell us why you are invoking a java class from bat file that too from a web application.

Answer (score 1):

If you know correctly which jar is referenced by class(I repeat if you exactly know) then you can do something like this

```
java -cp \WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jarName.jar mainClassToBeRun
```

hope this helps!

Good luck!